# Bootstrap not working fully in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-cycle2

Just finishing a [site](http://savannah100foundation.org/) and I am having trouble with the jQuery Cycle2 slider not working correctly in Firefox. It is totally responsive in Safari and Chrome and displays correctly.

In Firefox the images do not size down properly and stay full-sized as the window is reduced.

Here is the code for the slider:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=fade data-cycle-timeout=5000 data-cycle-slides="div.slide" >

<div class="slide">
<img src="http://dev.savannah100foundation.org/images/uploads/slide-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""  >
<div class="text-overlay hidden-xs">We make it easy for people to make a difference</div>
</div>

<div class="slide">
<img src="http://dev.savannah100foundation.org/images/uploads/slide-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""  >
</div>

<div class="slide">
<img src="http://dev.savannah100foundation.org/images/uploads/slide-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""  >
</div>

<div class="slide">
<img src="http://dev.savannah100foundation.org/images/uploads/slide-4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""  >
</div>


<div class="cycle-pager"></div>
</div><!-- /.cycle-slideshow -->
```

Comment: have you tried with removing img-responsive class from images?

Comment: I tried removing img-responsive, but it does not make a difference. Thanks.

Comment: a short while back I implemented a slider in which all images were same size and the responsiveness was working as expected and later I implemented another where images were different size and this time responsiveness was working but bigger images were not scaling back ...so i ended up writing media query adjustments for them. I hope that makes sense in some way for your case!

Comment: Looks like I may have to do media queries - which is odd.